# Convert schema-aware stylesheet

Tags: xslt, xsd, saxon

I have a schema-aware `XSLT` transformation that works well. However, the anticipated users of the `XSLT` will likely not have access to a *schema-aware processor*. Thus, I'd like to write some code that will convert my schema-aware `XSLT` into an XSLT that can be used by basic level conforming processors.

For my purposes, the use of schema-aware constructs is limited to matching templates, i.e.
`<xsl:template match="element(*, Candidate)">...</>`

I'm not expecting this to be a fully automatic process. What I would like is to generate an `XSLT` that would, for every `complexType` in an `XSD`, find its use in a specified surfaced `XSD` `element`.

Example code:

```xml
<xsd:schema xmlns="example.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="example.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.0">
    <xsd:element name="Candidate" type="Candidate"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Candidate">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Code" type="Code" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PartyId" type="Code" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="Code">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The expected output for the element `Candidate` would be something like this:

```xml
<complexType_usages>
  <usage complexType="Code" path="Candidate/Code" />
  <usage complexType="Code" path="Candidate/Party" />
</complexType_usages>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be simplest to work from a validated instance rather than trying to analyse the schema (so long as the instance is sufficiently representative). For every element, output the type annotation (using saxon:type-annotation) and the path, then take the list of type/path pairs, and eliminate duplicates and redundancy.